# function_to_pmml not a complete pmml

Tags: pmml

I have a model that will be used in java.  I would like to reduce the amount of development time by exporting functions written in R to pmml.

as an experiment I tried function_to_pmml which creates an incomplete pmml lacking headers

a normal pmml file includes headers etc like

the java developers can not use the output from "function_to_pmml("1 + 3/5 - (4 * 2)")"

how do I get a complete pmml?
I was thinking I might be able to do something like add_attributes but not found an example of this working

Answer (score 0):

You can export (in formula-) R expressions to PMML using the [R2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml) package.

Comment: Can you point me to an example?  I've exported a model using R2PMML but what I'm trying to do is add some additional calculations to say calculate the profit from a probability coming from a logistic regression

Comment: So the question is not about feature pre-processing, but about prediction post-processing. Sorry, the R2PMML package does not have that capability right now.

Comment: thanks, that is what I was wondering.  I have a model that I can convert to pmml but there is a fair amount of post processing I can either write requirements to be given to the java developers or I can find a way of converting a function that does the post processing